# wso2 MB's topic behaves as queue

Tags: wso2, jms, wso2-message-broker, wso2-esb

I am new to Wso2 EI and MB. I have named a 'topic.salesOrderTopic=salesOrderTopic' in jndi properties file. And, i have configured a message store in EI having parameters as below :

```
<messageStore class="org.apache.synapse.message.store.impl.jms.JmsStore" name="salesOrderJmsStore" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <parameter name="store.jms.destination">salesOrderJmsStore</parameter>
    <parameter name="store.producer.guaranteed.delivery.enable">false</parameter>
    <parameter name="store.jms.cache.connection">false</parameter>
    <parameter name="java.naming.factory.initial">org.wso2.andes.jndi.PropertiesFileInitialContextFactory</parameter>
    <parameter name="connectionfactory.QueueConnectionFactory">amqp://admin:admin@clientID/carbon?brokerlist='tcp://localhost:5675'</parameter>
    <parameter name="store.jms.JMSSpecVersion">1.1</parameter> </messageStore>
```

I have also configured two message processor in my machine (deployed with same proxy which publishes using the above message store). I could also see two consumers in MB. Strange thing is only one processor is processing the published message. Another one is not. If i deactivate the active processor, the other processor is processing the message with no problem.  Can you guys help me to understand where i am going wrong ?? I am expecting publish-subscribe model to work.

note : In MB, the salesOrderTopic is listed in both queue's list and topic list.

Comment: What do you mean by the "message processor"?

Comment: Message sampling processor : https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI611/Message+Sampling+Processor . sorry if i mislead it.